# Null condition is not checked in a react function component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

In my components, I want to check initially if there is an authenticated user or not:

```
const ReviewRoundOverall = (props) => {

    if (authenticationService.currentUserValue === null)
        history.push('/login');

    const currentUserId = authenticationService.currentUserValue["id"];

    //rest of the code
}
```

If I have two tabs, and if I sing out in one them, and then refresh the page in the second tab, I get the following error

> TypeError: authentication_service_1.default.currentUserValue is null

for line `const currentUserId = authenticationService.currentUserValue["id"];`

If I refresh the page again, the user is navigated to `/login` page without errors. I wonder why in the first refresh `if (authenticationService.currentUserValue === null)` is not working.

Also, I have the `NavMenu` in which all components are nested, where I have the following code:

```
const NavMenu2 = (props) => {

    if (authenticationService.currentUserValue == null || authenticationService.currentUserValue["id"] == null) {
        authenticationService.logout();
        history.push('/login');
    }


    useEffect(() => {
        if (authenticationService.currentUserValue == null || authenticationService.currentUserValue["id"] == null) {
            authenticationService.logout();
            history.push('/login');
        }

        authenticationService.currentUser.subscribe(x => set_CurrentUser(x));
    }, []);

}
```

This again does not solve the problem.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it is throwing the error there because the line `history.push('/login');` is happening **asynchronously** which means the rest of the code will run before redirecting to login page.

So my suggestion would be to do the following:

```
const ReviewRoundOverall = (props) => {
   if (authenticationService.currentUserValue === null) {
      history.push('/login');
   } else {
      const currentUserId = authenticationService.currentUserValue["id"];

      //rest of the code
   }
}
```

By doing this you won't get the error message once you have `null` value for `currentUserValue`.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! this works if I also return something (`null` in this case).

Comment: Great! Happy to help anytime. Please consider accepting as the answer if it solved your problem, thanks!